# Determining a functions output as print or write

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to determine the output of a function if whether the function is printing a statement, or writing it out on a .txt file. Is there a way to do this in Python? I thought perhaps the hasattr('myfunction', '**str**') might work, but it did not.

Examples of functions:

```
def x():
    print('dog')

def y():
    open("file.txt", "w").write("dog")
```

Comment: why not return something that tell you what you are doing?

Comment: I might be wrong, but that sounds like an undecidable problem in general (i.e. you could reduce it to the halting problem).

Comment: Maybe you can read the code?

Comment: I'm working with a project with 20 or so modules built by others, and there are some methods I need to test, and I need to know if the output its returning is a .txt or if they're verbosing it to screen, so I can use my function to copy that output into an automated report.

Comment: Well, just make a script to read it. Otherwise, you'll have to read it.

Comment: In that case though, if anyone ever adds more modules into the system, I would have to keep adding conditions on each method by going back into the module and seeing what they wrote. I just don't think that's practical at the end of the day. So, I'm assuming that there's no clean way to do this?

Comment: You can use inspect (https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html ) and read the code the functions and then use regular expressions to check their behavior (or even better, create your own python compiler, using this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html), but... don't... just don't... **:-D**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print function can take more arguments than just whats going to be written:

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)
```

So you could write a wrapper function for print that also appends a boolean to a list that is true if the file was sys.stdout and false otherwise.

```
import sys

write_history = []
def write(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout):
    print(*objects, sep=sep, end=end, file=file)
    write_history.append(file==sys.stdout)
```

Then just always use the write function, and when you want to test the output of a function, simply clear the write_history and call that function.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of doing something like this with subprocess (awk piping), but this will work for me definitely.